# For the equality $x_1^2=x_2$ to be true,the value of $a$ must be

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the point of maximum and point of minimum respectively of the function $f(x)=2x^3-9ax^2+12a^2x+1$,then for the equality $x_1^2=x_2$ to be true,the value of $a$ must be $(A)0$
$(B)2$
$(C)1$
$(D)\frac{1}{4}$

---

My attempt:$f'(x_1)=0,f'(x_2)=0$
$f'(x_1)=6x_1^2-18ax_1+12a^2=0............(1)$
$f'(x_2)=6x_2^2-18ax_2+12a^2=0.............(2)$
Subtracting (1) and (2),we get $6x_1+6x_2-18a=0$ after cancelling $x_1-x_2.$
$x_1+x_2-3a=0$
$x^2_1+x_1-3a=0$

I am stuck here.Answer is $a=2$

Comment: Solve the quadratic equations (1) and (2) separately. Don't subtract. Hint: $f'(x)=6(x-a)(x-2a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a>0$.

Hence, since $f'(x)=6(x-a)(x-2a),$ we obtain $a^2=2a$ and $a=2$.

Let $a<0$.

Hence, $4a^2=a$, which is impossible.

It's impossible that $a=0$, which gives the answer: $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=2x^3−9ax^2+12a^2x+1$

$f'(x)=6x^2-18ax+12a^2=6(x-a)(x-2a)=0$ when $x=a,2a$.

Since $x_2=x_1^2\ge0$ and $x_2$ is $a$ or $2a$, we have $a\ge0$. But $a=0$ is impossible as it would give $f(x)=2x^3+1$ which has no maximum or minimum points. Therefore $a>0$.

$f''(x)=12x-18a$; since $f''(a)<0$ and $f''(2a)>0$, the local maximum is at $x=a=x_1$ and the local minimum at $x=2a=x_2$. Hence $x_1^2=x_2$ $\implies$ $a^2=2a$ $\implies$ $a=2$.